# Why does only the last JPanel I add to a JFrame resize?

Tags: java, swing

So I am working on a GUI application using the swing framework. In short, I have 3 JPanels that act as different views of my application. Now the problem is that no matter the order I add the JPanels to my JFrame, only the *final* JPanel I add resizes when I switch to that view.

Some relevant bits of code:

When creating the window, I first create each individual JPanel, and add it to the JFrame:

```
 JPanel newPanel = new SomeClassExtendingJPanel();
 this.jframe.add(newPanel);
```

Next, whenever I switch between views of the application, I hide the panel that is currently active:

```
 jframe.validate();
 jframe.repaint();
 oldPanel.setVisible(false);
```

And then activate the to be shown panel:

```
 jframe.validate();
 jframe.repaint();
 newPanel.setVisible(true);
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resize the JFrame with each swap, you could call `pack()` on it, but this is kludgy having a GUI resize all the time. A better solution is to use the mechanism that Swing has for swapping views -- a CardLayout. This will size the container to the largest dimension necessary to adequately display all of the "card" components.

Check out the [CardLayout tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) and the [CardLayout API](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) for more on this.

Comment: Where should the layoutmanager be? If I, say, create a new JPanel that acts as the container for all the other JPanels, will that JPanel actually resize when the JFrame resizes?

Comment: See the [Nested Layout Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/about-swing-and-jtable/5630271#5630271) for ideas on how to combine layouts.

Answer (score 2):

JFrame's ContentPane has implemented [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html) by Default, and there is possible to put only one `JComponents` to the one `Area`,

you have to change used [LayoutManager](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) or put another JPanels to the other `Areas`